# What Role or Security Permission is required to edit the Placeholder and Datasource fields of a component?

Tags: experience-editor, security, permissions

We are setting up permission for users of our site, and have assigned our users to the roles `sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring` and `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing`.

However this does not allow the user to edit the `Placeholder` and `Data Source` fields of the component as you can see they are greyed out.

[image: Fields Greyed out]

What changes do I need to make to make these fields editable?

**Update**

Full User Roles

- sitecore\Sitecore Client Users
- sitecore\Author
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Social Authoring
- sitecore\Analytics Testing
- sitecore\Analytics Personalization
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring
- sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing

Comment: can you try to add just Sitecore\Author role?

Comment: They are already a member of Sitecore\Author, I'll add the full roles to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by adding `Read` and `Write` permissions for my role on the  `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters/__Standard Values` item.

[image: Rendering Parameters Permissions]

Comment: when you say, 'my role', is that a custom role, or did you modify access rights on a Sitecore role?

Comment: This is his custom role

Comment: Setting custom permissions is always a bad practice, especially with next upgrade you'll have to repeat this process all over again.

Comment: @ElenaZlateva Its a custom role that inherits the Sitecore roles.

Comment: @SergejsKravcenko I have serialized these changes to source control so they will be reapplied.

Comment: @WesleyLomax , i am trying to do exactly what your question was, i have added all the roles that you have listed. I am still not able to achieve it...can you tell me in details

Answer (score 6):

You have two options here:

1. Sitecore/Designer role has the permissions you need and I'd recommend to use it if you need to edit Data Source and Placeholder.
2. Grant Write access for the "Client Designing" to the /sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters/__Standard Values item.

But be careful; if one role has access rights but the other doesn't, you won't have access rights to the item until you override access directly to an user of that role.