# What role to add to show just the presentation details

Tags: role-management, user-management

I'm creating roles for the `Author` user who should be able to add components to the page (along with creating & editing content).
This user has only two roles now - `Sitecore client authoring` & `Sitecore client developing`.

**ISSUE 1:**
After assigning the `Sitecore client developing` role to this user, it displays `Analyze`, `Configure`, `Presentation` & `View` tabs in the ribbon.

But, I just want the `Presentation` tab to be shown & hide these - `Analyze`, `Configure`, `View`.

**ISSUE 2:**
When clicked on the `Edit` button for a rendering, the placeholder & datasource fields are readonly & non-editable.

What other role settings should be made to solve these issues.

Using `Sitecore 8.2`

Comment: sitecore client designing, I believe

Comment: @MarkCassidy. That worked. But when I click on a component to add the datasource, the fields are read-only. When I checked the actual datasources item, this user has access to it.

Comment: Can you try adding sitecore client authoring as well

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay It's there already.I've not removed it.

Comment: @Qwerty Just keep sitecore client designing and sitecore client authoring. No other roles.

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay. You have clearly not understood. It is already mentioned that those 2 are the only roles and they are present already. Just curious, have you tested it in your system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding just these two roles - 
`Sitecore\Designer` & `Sitecore\Author`

Found the solution [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/what-role-or-security-permission-is-required-to-edit-the-placeholder-and-datasou?rq=1)

Comment: Even when self-answering, you need to fill in a proper answer. Link-only answers are not accepted here.

Comment: @MarkCassidy. The solution was to know what roles to inherit to achieve the result & I have mentioned those in this answer. Please let me know what else to be updated in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can do it by roles but there is an alternative for it.

Give three below roles to user:

1. Sitecore client users
2. Designer
3. Analytics personalization

Now select the user and go to security editor, select the item and click on assign in ribbon and give "Write" permission to that item or at folder level(if many) and select checkboxes "item" & "descendants".

Now user should be able to edit personalization related things.

Comment: It did not work. The placeholder & Datasource fields are still readonly

Comment: updated my answer so you need to add one more role that is "sitecore\Analytics Personlization"